# Undefined method: assert_not_nil in Minitest

Tags: ruby, minitest, testunit

I'm trying to execute the following code, but it is giving me an undefined method error:

```
require 'minitest/autorun'
require 'string_extension'

class StringExtensionTest < Minitest::Test
  def test_humanize_returns_nothing
    assert_not_nil "Yo".humanize, "humanize is returning nil."
  end
end
```

I'm trying to execute this code from Codeschool's Rails course, but it seems that there is no method `assert_not_nil`. I've also checked the documentation for MiniTest framework, and neither it is defined there, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Here](http://docs.seattlerb.org/minitest/Minitest/Assertions.html) you can find the list of assertions defined by `MiniTest`.

As you can see, `assert_not_nil` is not defined. There's a lot of possible assertions that `MiniTest` doesn't define, but it's also true that any assertion can be defined with the simplest assertion ever possible [`assert`](http://docs.seattlerb.org/minitest/Minitest/Assertions.html#method-i-assert).

In your specific case:

```
assert result != nil
```

You can also pass a custom message

```
assert result != nil, "Expected something to not be nil"
```

Comment: Well that was the information I needed to know if I should change to `MiniTest::Test` or stick with `Test::Unit::TestCase`. Basic `assert` doesn't produce readable error message so `Test::Unit::TestCase` it is.

Answer (score 6):

`assert_not_nil` is just an alias for `refute_nil`, but it's Rails-only, not part of standard Minitest.  Changing your test to extend ActiveSupport::TestCase should do the trick:

```
class StringExtensionTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def test_humanize_returns_nothing
    assert_not_nil "Yo".humanize, "humanize is returning nil."
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`assert !!result` has worked for me. `!!` means "convert to boolean" (literally double negation).

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
assert "Yo".humanize
```

In ruby everthing but `nil` and `false` is true-ish.

UPDATE: since you want to check explicetly for not nil:

```
refute_nil "Yo".humanize
```

But in the scenario you describe i'd actually check for the return value to be what I expect. Consider:

```
class String
  def humanize
    false
  end
end

refute_nil "Yo".humanize
assert_equal "Yo", "Yo".humanize
```

Comment: Well, it will check that it does return something, while I'd like to check it the other way.

Comment: "assert <anything>" doesn't work when <anything> is nil - I'm surprised, frankly. I have to do `assert !!<anything>` to make it work.